# for each element type in body

Tags: javascript, dom

For example

```
For each div in body
          div.innerHtml = "poo"
next div
```

this is obviously psuedo code but demonstrates what i am trying to do.

---

Edit to share that it gives me tremendous joy to look at questions 9-years old and to see how far I've come and that this question still benefits others.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "foo";
}​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pyGhg/)

If you want to look only in the `<body>`:

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "foo";
}​
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] === document.body` ;)

Answer (score 41):

**NodeList.forEach**
[image: Chrome icon]
[image: Firefox icon]
[image: Edge icon]
[image: Opera icon]
[image: Safari icon]<sup>**10**</sup>

`querySelectorAll` returns a static non-live `NodeList` exposing a `forEach` method:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

elements.forEach( el => {
  el.innerHTML = "foo";
});
```

[Document.querySelectorAll<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
[NodeList.prototype.forEach()<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

---

**Array.from**
[image: Chrome icon]
[image: Firefox icon]
[image: Edge icon]
[image: Opera icon]
[image: Safari icon]<sup>**9**</sup>

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

Array.from(elements).forEach( (el) => {
  el.innerHTML = "foo";
});
```

[Array.from()<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

---

**Array Destructuring**
[image: Chrome icon]
[image: Firefox icon]
[image: Edge icon]
[image: Opera icon]
[image: Safari icon]<sup>**9**</sup>

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[...elements].forEach( el => {
  el.innerHTML = "foo";
});
```

[Destructuring assignment<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
[Document.querySelectorAll()<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

---

**Array forEach.call**
[image: Chrome icon]
[image: Firefox icon]
[image: Edge icon]
[image: IExplor icon]<sup>**9**</sup>
[image: Opera icon]
[image: Safari icon]

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[].forEach.call(elements, function( el ) {
  el.innerHTML = "foo";
});
```

[Array.prototype.forEach()<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

---

**For loop**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = "foo";
}
```

[Element.getElementsByTagName()<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 5):

Easy job:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

And now:

```
// VanillaJS / JavaScript puro
var lista_de_divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')
lista_de_divs.forEach(function (div, i) {
    // código...
    console.log(i, div)
})


// jQuery
$('div').forEach(function (div, i) {
    // código...
    console.log(i, div)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

For ES6

```
let elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, e => {
  e.innerHTML = "foo";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate version with the new [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in ES2015:

```js
Array.from(document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")).forEach(a=>a.innerHTML='foo');
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>Test</div>
<div></div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
```

If size is absolutely crucial for you, then this solution is only 84 bytes, compared to 113 for @Roko's answer and 120 for @gdoron's.

In that case, jQuery could shorten this far more:

```js
$("body div").html('foo');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>Test</div>
<div></div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
```

Now only 26 bytes!

Comment: Interesting examples, but you cannot talk about *size* and jQuery cause it's a library on top of JS and *has it's size* on it's own. Thumbs up for the JS version BTW (even though I'd use querySelectorAll ;)