# Turn JS popup editable when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am basically creating a phonebook web app just as a starting point to my learning in web development. I've created contacts and I have made the contact details displayable as a popup when the particular contact is clicked.

What I would like further is to make each of the fields of the contact details editable! I would probably place an "edit" link at the side of each field and when that is clicked I would like the respective field to become editable.

I've searched, but I couldn't find a solution.

PS: My first question here, so apologies if its not to the point or something.

Comment: you can switch, the string to input field, for example when click into the text

Comment: Hi, what framework you're using? is it plain javascript?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding service ___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service. There are many scripts readily available on web for doing what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simple. You have to make tree elements for each contact:

1. contact tex(you already did that)
2. edit(button that contains onclick="myFunction()")
3. Hidden text field(style="display:none;")

```js
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("txtB").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("txt").style.display = "none";
}

function finishedEdit(){
document.getElementById("txtB").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("txt").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtB").value;
}
```

```html
    <span style="display:block;" id="txt">George Bush</span><input onchange="finishedEdit()" id="txtB" type="text" value="George Bush" style="display:none;"/><button onclick="myFunction()">Edit</button>
```

This is not exactly what you want but I can't do much more because I can't see your code.

Comment: You almost got my whole problem. However for displaying the contact details, I'm retrieving the name and other details of the person by sending an ajax request to the database and then I'm filling my table cells using "document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML=". So, in this case, if i put the "input-text" field in the same cell its not working!

Comment: Then separate them using <div> tags and retrieve information only from div where first text is... I'm not good with ajax, that's why I might be wrong

Comment: Got the solution! Just now looked at your reply! By the way, I used separate id's for the td tags and hid/displayed the td tags themselves and also used another separate id for the input field! That solved the problem!

Comment: Nonetheless, I need to repeat the above procedure for each and every contact detail. For eg: Name, phone no, email ID etc.. I'll simply be repeating these functions by changing the id's. Feels a bit redundant! Any other way to eliminate this?

Comment: Yes, use for each, I will insert a link now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964163/for-each-element-type-in-body

Comment: Nah! This only works if I want to apply something similar for a certain category! But in my case, I'm having separate td id's for Name, Phone no,..etc . Nonetheless, what I have decided to go with is function overloading. I would just pass the tag id as an argument to the function! Cheers!

Comment: Yeah but you could manage to do what you want even with for each but it is not so simple so, go ahead and do it your way

Comment: Oh! Can you show me how you could do it using for each in my case if you can?

Comment: I can't because I don't know how does your code look like exactly. You can update question and add your code, then I could help. Thanks for accepting my answer :)