# Select div with a text inside in JS

Tags: javascript, html, class, select

I want to modify a div with a special text inside like this.

```
<div>
<p>
A global issue
</p>
</div>
```

How can I get it in JS without using id or class ? And only the div with the text "A global issue".

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what do you want to do with that `text` then? `document.querySelector("div p").innerHTML`

Comment: I want to add style on the div in JS display none

Comment: can I ask why you can't have an id?

Comment: Because it's a div create by a module and I don't have an access to him

Comment: Note to those answering the question: the OP has not tagged, or implied, that s/he is using jQuery. While jQuery can certainly be used, it's not required, and - honestly - plain JavaScript should be used in questions where a specific library is not featured in the question's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target the div and set it to `display: none` you can run either:

```
// Pure JS
document.querySelector("div p").style.display = "none"
// w/jQuery
$('div p').hide();
```

If there's more then one `div p` tags in your HTML, you can also search by text using the following:

```
$('div p:contains("A global issue")').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: This would work if that was the only code on the html page, but as OP said: it has to be the div with "A global issue", and none of the others.

Comment: Thanks for calling me out I didn't catch that. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery:

```js
$('div:contains("A global issue")').css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<div>A global issue</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use simple javascript solution, see snippet below

First, get all divs from page

Second, store your search text in a variable

Third, loop through all divs and find the one containing your text, then you can do whatever you want with it. I added a backgroundColor red to it

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var myText = "A global issue";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  if (divs[i].textContent.indexOf(myText) > 0 ) {
  divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    A global issue
  </p>
  <p>
    More text here
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    Not a good text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should mention the caveats of using `indexOf` over the exactness of matching an exact text... oh wait... or you could use some regexp instead?! ;)

Comment: well i am sure there are ways to change my answer to be better :) you are free to add your changes :D thanks for pointing out the limitations of the use of indexOf

Answer (score 0):

```
let i=5;
let divs =Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('div > p')); // it returns array
divs[i].style.display= "none";
```

Edit:

`for(let i=0;i<divs.length;i++){ if(divs[i].textContent==="some text"){ divs[i].style.display="none"; } }`

if you want to change parent node do `divs[i].parentNode.style.display="none"`

Comment: Just a notice (if not obvious to someone stumbling upon) that by using `let`, `Array.from` you just excluded every version of IE. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664363/383904