# How to adjust WKWebview's container content height to the webview content?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, height, wkwebview

I'm trying to get correct height and width of my `WKWebview` content, to set the webview container height to the webview content.
I have already tried a lot of solutions found on stack overflow.

With this code, the container has the correct height, but the webview's width is too large (as if the webview was zoomed)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let customFrame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: self.viewForWebview.frame.size.height))
    self.webView = WKWebView (frame: customFrame , configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.viewForWebview.addSubview(webView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
         self.webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.viewForWebview.topAnchor),
        self.webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.viewForWebview.bottomAnchor),
        self.webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.viewForWebview.leadingAnchor),
        self.webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.viewForWebview.trailingAnchor)
        ])

    webView.uiDelegate = self
     webView.navigationDelegate = self
     webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

    let bodyHtml = "<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />" + htmlString + "</body></html>";  
    webView.loadHTMLString(bodyHtml, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    self.heightWebviewConstraint.constant = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}
```

Instead adding `<head>` tag, I also tried to use `evaluateJavaScript`, but in this case, the height's container is too big, and the webview's width too large.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
                self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in

                self.heightWebviewConstraint.constant = height as! CGFloat
                self.view.setNeedsLayout()
                self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            })
        }

    })
}
```

I also tried to add specific css style (without `viewport` and without `evaluateJavaScript`), in this case webview's width is ok, but height's container is too small (my webview is cropped at top and bottom).

```
let bodyHtml = "<html><head> <style>  img {  width:auto; height:auto;  max-width:100%; </style></head><body>" + htmlString + "</body></html>"
```

I'm lost with all these solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are actually pretty close to a solution there. I've faced a similar problem and managed to solve it with evaluating javascript. Our implementation is a little bit different since we use a stackview with nested WkWebViews as arranged subviews. But I can share our code (stripped out the stackview parts) and you can try it out yourself.

```
    func addAndLoadWebView(with url: URL) {
         let wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100))
         wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
         wkWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
         wkWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
         wkWebView.scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
         wkWebView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
         self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)
         wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    @available(iOS 12.0, *)
    func asyncGetHTMLHeight(_ webview: WKWebView, completion: @escaping (CGFloat) -> Void) {
        webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight") { (result, _) in
            guard let result = result as? CGFloat else {
                completion(0.0)
                return
            }
            completion(result)
        }
    } 

    @available(iOS 12.0, *)
    func compatibleMeasureImageContent(with webview: WKWebView) {
    webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.firstChild.offsetHeight") { (result, _) in
        guard let result = result as? CGFloat else {
            return
        }
        var height = result
        webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.firstChild.width") { (result, _) in
            guard let width = result as? CGFloat else {
                return
            }
            // do something with width and height here
            // in our case images come 1 by one since our html is delivered in parts. You might have to check each image tag for its height for this calculation to work.
            }
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
         self.asyncGetHTMLHeight(webView, completion: { newHeight in
             webView.frame.size.height = newHeight
             webView.removeConstraints(webView.constraints)
             webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: newHeight).isActive = true          
          })
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, new result: the height's container is too big, and the web view's width too small :(

Comment: Are you loading strictly html or PDF's?

Comment: Realized we actually add some HTML normalizing to the code before it's injected. Not sure if it helps but can link it aswell.

Comment: html with only <img> tags inside

Comment: Hmm images are a bit tricky, you might have to write some javascript to check each image tag. We actually calculate height differently for images.

Comment: I haven’t enough knowledges to write JavaScript myself :( do you have some examples?

Comment: This answer is really simple and straight forward for iterating all elements in a body:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964163/for-each-element-type-in-body