# How do I add a div to a parent element in a navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a navigation menu with class name: "custom-menu-class". It's in Wordpress.

I want to make an active class meaning that when a link is active (url matches), and/or mouse hovers a link, a div is inserted in the parent element (a white circle on top of the text).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9YFB.png)

Playing around with inspect element, I found that adding:

```html
<div style="
    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15%;
    left: 33%;
">
</div>
```

to the parent element gives me what I need.

I also need it for the active menu item only.

Can someone help me? Trying to achieve this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8iW5.png)

Comment: This can be done using CSS only: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zmwpoy0b/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't insert a `div` — I would use the `::before` pseudo-element. Read more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

If you are using a [WordPress menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) `wp_nav_menu()`, WP will automatically add `.current-menu-item` to the current menu item `li` — meaning if you are at [www.example.com/contact](http://www.example.com/contact) — the **contact** menu item will be given the `.current-menu-item` class. Here's a screenshot of the markup:

[image]

For any hovering styling you would just use `:hover` — read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

Using the [Twenty Twenty](https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/about/?demo) theme's menu markup, here is what I would do — *I added in bootstrap just for demo purposes*.

```css
/* For demo purposes */
ul {
  background-color: #999;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Start custom styles */
ul li {
  position: relative;
}

ul li.current-menu-item a::before,
ul li a:hover::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="primary-menu-wrapper" aria-label="Horizontal" role="navigation">
  <ul class="primary-menu reset-list-style row">
    <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-90 col-auto">
      <a href="https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/?demo">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75 col-auto">
      <a href="https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/exhibitions/?demo">Exhibitions</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-73"
      class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-69 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-73 col-auto">
      <a href="https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/about/?demo" aria-current="page">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74 col-auto">
      <a href="https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/blog/?demo">News</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```css
/* For demo purposes */
ul {
  background-color: #999;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Start custom styles */
ul li {
  position: relative;
}

ul li.current-menu-item a::before,
ul li a:hover::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="primary-menu-wrapper" aria-label="Horizontal" role="navigation">
  <ul class="primary-menu reset-list-style row">
    <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-90 col-auto">
      <a href="https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/?demo">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75 col-auto">
      <a href="https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/exhibitions/?demo">Exhibitions</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-73"
      class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-69 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-73 col-auto">
      <a href="https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/about/?demo" aria-current="page">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74 col-auto">
      <a href="https://twentytwentydemo.wordpress.com/blog/?demo">News</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

exactly what you expected. i have written small js function to toggle between active class.

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-box li a");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    for (var j = 0; j < btns.length; j++) {
      btns[j].classList.remove('active')
    }
    e.target.classList.add('active')

  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.menu-container {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.menu-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 15px
}

.menu-box li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-box li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-box li a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-box li a.active:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-box li a:before {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .3s
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-container">
  <ul class="menu-box">
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#emissione">Emisione</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: JavaScript  is unnecessary, since on click the page navigates (read OP's question) and therefore another link will be *current*

Comment: yes, in fact, that's reason i didn't use jQuery in the example

Comment: I meant JavaScript, sorry. So yeah JS, jQuery, whatever.

Comment: PS,  `btns` is a **NodeList** so you could use the NodeList's `.forEach()` Method instead of doing `for` loops

Comment: yeah but as far i know forEach is not supported my old browser like ie8, thats's why i used for loop in this example and also i used js just to show the example, then it depends on him, how he wants to implement this in wordpress. As far i know, there's a default active link available in wordpress.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664363/383904 - Also, nobody uses IE8 any more. Even IE11 support is getting scarse.

Comment: Yes, i agree with that @RokoC.Buljan but we can ignore the JS part here, that was just for example, Note: we can't say nobody: It won't be appropriate. check this: https://www.w3counter.com/trends,